# Python convert timestamps with specific timezone to datetime in UTC

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I'm trying to convert a timestamp with a specific timezone(Europe/Paris) to a datetime format in UTC. 
From my laptop it works with the solution below but when I'm executing my code in a remote server(AWS- Lambda function in Ireland), I've a shift of 1 hour because the local timezone of the server is different from mine. 
How can I have a code who can work on my laptop and at the same time in a remote server(dynamically handle local timezone)?

```
import pytz
import datetime

def convert_timestamp_in_datetime_utc(timestamp_received):
    utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
    now_in_utc = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc).astimezone(pytz.UTC)
    fr = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')
    new_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_received)
    return fr.localize(new_date, is_dst=None).astimezone(pytz.UTC)
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - how is this failing? What is "timestamp_received"? The only reason I can imagine this failing is if the timestamp is a timestamp in *local time*.

Comment: It's a timestamp extracted from a French website which is based on the local timezone(Europe/Paris). When I executed this function, the return datetime has a shift of one hour if I executed it on my laptop or by a Lambda function. I'm suppose the problem is that "datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp" is based on the local timezone...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure what `timestamp_received` is, but I think what you want is `utcfromtimestamp()`

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

def convert_timestamp_in_datetime_utc(timestamp_received):
    dt_naive_utc = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp_received)
    return dt_naive_utc.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

For completeness, here is another way to accomplish the same thing by referencing [`python-dateutil`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)'s `tzlocal` time zone:

```
from dateutil import tz
from datetime import datetime
def convert_timestamp_in_datetime_utc(timestamp_received):
    dt_local = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_received, tz.tzlocal())

    if tz.datetime_ambiguous(dt_local):
        raise AmbiguousTimeError

    if tz.datetime_imaginary(dt_local):
        raise ImaginaryTimeError

    return dt_local.astimezone(tz.tzutc())


class AmbiguousTimeError(ValueError):
    pass

class ImaginaryTimeError(ValueError):
    pass
```

(I added in the `AmbiguousTimeError` and `ImaginaryTimeError` conditions to mimic the `pytz` interface.) Note that I'm including this just in case you have a similar problem that needs to make reference to the local time zone for some reason - if you have something that will give you the right answer in UTC, it's best to use that and then use `astimezone` to get it into whatever local zone you want it in.

**How it works**

Since you expressed that you were still a bit confused about how this works in the comments, I thought I would clarify why this works. There are two functions that convert timestamps to `datetime.datetime` objects, [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) and [`datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp):

1. `utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)` will give you a *naive* `datetime` that represents the time in UTC. You can then do `dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)` (or any other `utc` implementation - `datetime.timezone.utc`, `dateutil.tz.tzutc()`, etc) to get an aware datetime and convert it to whatever time zone you want.
2. `fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=None)`, when `tz` is not `None`, will give you an *aware* `datetime` equivalent to `utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(tz)`. If `tz` is `None`, instead of converting too the specified time zone, it converts to your local time (equivalent to `dateutil.tz.tzlocal()`), and then returns a *naive* `datetime`.

Starting in Python 3.6, you can use [`datetime.datetime.astimezone(tz=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) on *naive* datetimes, and the time zone will be assumed to be system local time. So if you're developing a Python >= 3.6 application or library, you can use `datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).astimezone(whatever_timezone)` or `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(whatever_timezone)` as equivalents.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, it works with the first solution! Still really confusing for me the datetime/timestamp manipulation with different timezone :(

Comment: @Matt I updated my answer, hopefully that clarifies what's going on.

Comment: thanks alot for your explanation! It's more clear now for me.